# Scipy.curve_fit() vs. Matlab fit() weighted nonlinear least squares

Tags: matlab, scipy-optimize

I have a Matlab reference routine that I am trying to convert to numpy/scipy.  I have encountered a curve fitting problem that does I cannot solve in Python.  So here is a simple example which demonstrates the problem.  The data is completely synthetic and not part of the problem.

Let's say I'm trying to fit a straight-line model of noisy data -

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [0.1075, 1.3668, 1.5482, 3.1724, 4.0638, 4.7385, 5.9133, 7.0685, 8.7157, 9.5539]
```

For the unweighted solution in Matlab, I would code

```
g = @(m, b, x)(m*x + b)
f = fittype(g)
bestfit = fit(x, y, g)
```

which produces a solution of `bestfit.m = 1.048`, `bestfit.b = -0.09219`

Running this data through `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` produces identical results.

If instead the fit uses a decay function to reduce the impact of data points

```
dw = [0.7290, 0.5120, 0.3430, 0.2160, 0.1250, 0.0640, 0.0270, 0.0080,  0.0010, 0]
weightedfit = fit(x, y, g, 'Weights', dw)
```

This produces a slope if 0.944 and offset 0.1484.

I have not figured out how to conjure this result from `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` using the sigma parameter.  If I pass the weights as provided to Matlab, the '0' causes a divide by zero exception.  Clearly Matlab and scipy are thinking very differently about the meaning of the weights in the underlying optimization routine.  Is there a simple way of converting between the two that allows me to provide a weighting function which produces identical results?

Comment: Did you observe any difference in robustness of curve fitting in Python vs Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after further investigation I can offer the answer, at least for this simple example.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize

def modelFun(x, m, b):
    return m * x + b

def testFit():
    w = np.diag([1.0, 1/0.7290, 1/0.5120, 1/0.3430, 1/0.2160, 1/0.1250, 1/0.0640, 1/0.0270, 1/0.0080, 1/0.0010])
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    y = np.array([0.1075, 1.3668, 1.5482, 3.1724, 4.0638, 4.7385, 5.9133, 7.0685, 8.7157, 9.5539])

    popt = sp.optimize.curve_fit(modelFun, x, y, sigma=w)

    print(popt[0])
    print(popt[1])
```

Which produces the desired result.

In order to force sp.optimize.curve_fit to minimize the same chisq metric as Matlab using the curve fitting toolbox, you must do two things:

1. Use the reciprocal of the weight factors
2. Create a diagonal matrix from the new weight factors.  According to the scipy reference:

> **sigma** None or M-length sequence or MxM array, optional
>   Determines the uncertainty in ydata. If we define residuals as r =
>   ydata - f(xdata, *popt), then the interpretation of sigma depends on
>   its number of dimensions:
>
> A 1-d sigma should contain values of standard deviations of errors in
>   ydata. In this case, the optimized function is chisq = sum((r / sigma)
>   ** 2).
>
> A 2-d sigma should contain the covariance matrix of errors in ydata.
>   In this case, the optimized function is chisq = r.T @ inv(sigma) @ r.
>
> New in version 0.19.
>
> None (default) is equivalent of 1-d sigma filled with ones.